# Mounting multiple volumes on a docker container?

Tags: docker

I know I can mount a directory in my host on my container using something like

```
docker run -t -i -v '/on/my/host:/on/the/container' ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Is there a way to create more than one host-container pair? e.g. a comma-separated list, or pass in an array?

Comment: as I understand current state of docs terms, you cannot mount a volume (title of question), you certainly can have many bind mounts to host folders (that is what is asked for in body of question)

Comment: do `docker run -t -i \
  -v '/on/my/host/test1:/on/the/container/test1' \
  -v '/on/my/host/test2:/on/the/container/test2' \
  ubuntu /bin/bash`.

Answer (score 389):

Pass multiple `-v` arguments.

For instance:

```
docker -v /on/my/host/1:/on/the/container/1 \
       -v /on/my/host/2:/on/the/container/2 \
       ...
```

Comment: Okay, so i'm doing this the exact same way but when i try calling the second one it says that it isn't found.

Comment: docker run -v /home/usr/workspace/proj/WebContent/file/username:/mycode -v /home/usr/workspace/proj/WebContent/file:/tst  gcc:4.9 sh -c 'cd mycode; gcc -o myapp ./mycode.c; cd tst; ./myapp < ./test.txt'
This is my command, I'm trying to compile the mycode.c that is in the first volume, but give that same file an stdin from a different volume. How do I do it?

Comment: Does it always need absolute paths?

Comment: The destination must always be absolute. The source needs to be either an absolute path or the identifier for a named volume -- see https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/ for docs on the latter.

Comment: this is working only for the second volume i am mapping... how can i map two volumes in the same run command assuming I can't use the docker file only run command

Comment: @thebeancounter, multiple `-v` arguments is *definitely* supported behavior upstream. See it used in the example in the upstream documentation at https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#remove-anonymous-volumes. Perhaps you might file a separate question with a [mcve] for your failure case?

Comment: @thebeancounter, ...you can also see that in the code yourself: https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/d57cc1782e08343de0e58930d5f181c4312d4003/cli/command/container/opts.go#L33 defines `volumes` as a `ListOpts`, and [`pflag.VarP`](https://godoc.org/github.com/spf13/pflag#VarP) is used to parse it -- which honors the type (as something that builds lists, vs parses single values). Similarly, you can see those arguments iterated over at https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/d57cc1782e08343de0e58930d5f181c4312d4003/cli/command/container/opts.go#L333

Comment: @CharlieParker, providing placeholders `img_name:tag` and `cmd` explicitly defeats the point of using `...` as a marker for "fill out all your other arguments here".

Answer (score 66):

Docker now recommends migrating towards using `--mount`.

Multiple volume mounts are also explained in detail in the current Docker documentation.

From: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

```
$ docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app \
  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/target,target=/app2,readonly,bind-propagation=rslave \
  nginx:latest
```

Original older answer should still work; just trying to keep the answer aligned to current best known method.

Comment: It's worth adding the only reason Docker recommend migrating is because their research shows --mount is easier to use and it has more options.  Using either -v or --mount is perfectly fine, this is down to your personal preference and needs.

Comment: what wrong with `docker run -v /Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis:/home/bot/iit-term-synthesis \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/pycoq:/home/bot/pycoq \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils:/home/bot/ultimate-utils \
           -ti brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test bash`?

Answer (score 35):

You can use `-v` option multiple times in `docker run` command to mount multiple directory in container:

```
docker run -t -i \
  -v '/on/my/host/test1:/on/the/container/test1' \
  -v '/on/my/host/test2:/on/the/container/test2' \
  ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: Does this add anything to [the preceding answer to the same effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18861869/14122)?

Comment: love this answer! With a concrete thing that is essentially runable and a useful interactive demo.

Answer (score 11):

You can have Read only or Read and Write only on the volume

```
docker -v /on/my/host/1:/on/the/container/1:ro \

docker -v /on/my/host/2:/on/the/container/2:rw \
```

Comment: which one is the default option?

Comment: @HammadDar Pretty sure 'rw' is the default for volumes. You could try testing it out locally without specifying ':rw' or ':ro' at the end.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows: if you had to mount two directories E:\data\dev & E:\data\dev2

Use:

```
docker run -v E:\data\dev:c:/downloads -v E:\data\dev2 c:/downloads2 -i --publish 1111:80 -P SomeBuiltContainerName:SomeLabel
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw a comment asking if read-write or read-only was the default option; read-write is the default option. (making a post because I haven't enough rep to comment)

Per [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume), running the following:

```
docker run -d \
--name devtest \
--mount source=myvol2,target=/app \
nginx:latest
```

and then using `docker inspect devtest` and locating the "RW" option in the "Mounts" section of the output:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/myvol2/_data",
        "Destination": "/app",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
],
```

lets us see that the default option lets the volume be both read- and write-able.

---

To set your volume as read-only (again per [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-read-only-volume)), add `readonly` after your `source` and `destination` tags:

```
docker run -d \
--name=nginxtest \
--mount source=nginx-vol,destination=/usr/share/nginx/html,readonly \
nginx:latest
```

Run `docker inspect nginxtest` and locate "Mounts":

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "volume",
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/nginx-vol/_data",
        "Destination": "/usr/share/nginx/html",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": false,
        "Propagation": ""
    }
],
```

(Note: I don't know why official documentation swaps between `target` and `destination` tags, but I am working under the assumption they can be used interchangeably.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31956015)

Answer (score 1):

For a runable example:

```bash
docker run -v /Users/brandomiranda/iit-term-synthesis:/home/bot/iit-term-synthesis \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/pycoq:/home/bot/pycoq \
           -v /Users/brandomiranda/ultimate-utils:/home/bot/ultimate-utils \
           -ti brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test bash
```

but first do:

```
docker pull brandojazz/iit-term-synthesis:test
```

Answer (score -12):

Or you can do

```
docker run -v /var/volume1 -v /var/volume2 DATA busybox true
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is after. This creates a volume within the container and doesn't bind it on the host.

Comment: You're right, should be:     docker run -v /var/volume1:/container/volume1 -v /var/volume2:/container/volume2 DATA busybox true