# How can i manage files in my host machine on Docker

Tags: docker, fileutils

I am using Docker on my Windows machine and i want to copy a directory to another directory in my Windows host. I have a Maven project that does this on Windows using org.apache.commons.FileUtils library and it works just fine. I want to run this Maven project in my Docker container so that i can move files on my Windows via Docker.

When i tried doing it, it gave no error but there was no copy process either. Can i manage files on my host machine with Docker?

Comment: No.  One of the major goals of Docker is that containers _can't_ access the host filesystem, without being given special permission by the operator.  Using the `cp` or `copy` command on the host will be much easier than trying to make this work via Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Most sensible anwwer: You should not want to do this.
If you are working in a Container, don't have dependencies to the Host.
Having dependencies to the Host contradicts why Docker exists.

But if you insist: You can do this by mapping the directories of the Host inside the Docker Container via Volumes.
And then you can copy inside the Docker container.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this: [Docker: How to live sync host folder with container folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878216/docker-how-to-live-sync-host-folder-with-container-folder)

And learn about docker volumes from here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/