# MUP (meteor) deploy deletes files

Tags: meteor

Sadly although mup deploy works perfectly, I have a folder called ".uploads", which users can upload files into.

Each deploy deletes the files in the directory. I would like to exclude or protect the file from the deploy deleting the files, any ideas?

Currently I filed an issue: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/1022

Not sure if its an issue with mup or my system setup. I use tomitrescak:meteor-uploads and also cfs:file-collection. They both have the same issue.

Comment: Are you able to rename the folder and remove the dot prefix as folders with dot prefix are generally ignored in the build process for meteor

Comment: The issue is that I want user uploaded files to not be overwritten on the live website, not for me to be able to upload files from my local source folder. When I deploy the live website files that were uploaded by other users are deleted.

Comment: Apologies for misreading that, what about if you move the image directory to point to a folder outside the build path so mup doesn't redeploy the folder? I had this method working with mup and collectionfs filesystem a while back but ended up switching to use cfs with aws s3 buckets as it meant even if I redeploy the whole server the images persist and I can host multiple instances without worrying about redeploying images

Comment: I will try to post a solution later. It required mounting docker volumes so that you could access higher up in the file system architecture outside the dicker context like you had mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But from what I see it shall be easy to do, you need to modify the script at https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/blob/mupx/templates/linux/start.sh#L26

And add a new mapping. You can map multiple volumes such as following: [Mounting multiple volumes on a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861834/mounting-multiple-volumes-on-a-docker-container)

So your script would look like (mounting the folder on the host machine /opt/uploads/myapp to the folder /opt/uploads in the container):

```
docker run \
    -d \
    --restart=always \
    --publish=$PORT:80 \
    --volume=$BUNDLE_PATH:/bundle \
    --volume=/opt/uploads/myapp:/opt/uploads/ \      .... this is the new line
    --env-file=$ENV_FILE \
    --link=mongodb:mongodb \
    --hostname="$HOSTNAME-$APPNAME" \
    --env=MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/$APPNAME \
    --name=$APPNAME \
    meteorhacks/meteord:base
```

This can be found in "start.sh" in MUP until this issue is resolved and you can mount volumes via the options.

Also see discussion here: https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads/issues/235#issuecomment-228618130