# How can I access the project directories that are created in the Docker toolbox Linux containers on my Windows OS?

Tags: python, linux, windows, docker, containers

I have just installed Docker ToolBox on Windows 10 OS and created a Linux Python container. I have cloned a project from GitHub in that container.  How can I access the project directories that are created in the Linux containers on my Windows OS? Are they saved in any drive or directory?

I have obtained the docker image container using the command

```
docker pull floydhub/dl-docker:cpu
```

and running it using the command

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v /sharedfolder:/root/sharedfolder floydhub/dl-docker:cpu bash
```

Also I am running my project using docker quick start terminal, is there any other way (GUI based) to manage and run my projects?

Answer (score 0):

More details about how your Linux Python container was launched, I.E. the build file/ run command, would be helpful. But that being said, you can copy files out of a container using docker cp   as described here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

Also, if you use volumes you can view the cloned repo right on your Windows machine directly, but those volumes must be setup during the build process and cannot be added to a running container. More details on volumes and how data persistence works in docker:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/

To answer your question about a GUI docker tool, I've used Kitematic (https://kitematic.com/) but personally found the CLI faster and easier to use.

**Edit**
According to edits you do in fact have volumes that will persist data to your local Windows machine. But I believe you need to use a separate -v flag for each: (docker documentation is unclear about this as they now suggest using --mount, but according to this SO post: [Mounting multiple volumes on a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861834/mounting-multiple-volumes-on-a-docker-container) suggests the multiple flags):

```
docker -v /sharedfolder:/root/sharedfolder \
       -v floydhub/dl-docker:cpu
```

A side note: it is sometimes confusing to not use absolute paths when mounting volumes as you've done in floydhub/dl-docker:cpu. Its not always clear where this data might live.

Any data that is stored in the docker container at /root/sharedfolder should be available in Windows at /sharedfolder

**Edit 2**
To match your original docker run command:

```
docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v /sharedfolder:/root/sharedfolder -v floydhub/dl-docker:cpu bash
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I have updated the question about the commands please have a look.

Comment: I have just started using it, can i still view the volumes on my windows machine? I am using this image https://github.com/floydhub/dl-docker#why-do-i-need-a-docker.

Comment: Sir I tried both the commands docker -v /sharedfolder:/root/sharedfolder \
       -v floydhub/dl-docker:cpu                                                                            docker run -v /var/volume1:/floydhub/dl-docker:cpu/volume1 -v /var/volume2:/bilstm/volume2 DATA busybox true                                        But none of them is working

Comment: Your original docker statement looked right, was just missing a -v. I've updated my answer. Also, as mentioned in my previous reply, please ensure your paths are correct.